# Finite Summations can be Interchanged

Tags: matrices, summation

In the proof of associativity of matrix multiplication, the reason for one of the steps is given as -**Finite summations can be interchanged**. What is meant by this statement?

[image: Proof Snippet]

Comment: If an infinite series converges conditionally, it is possible to rearrange the terms of the series in such a way that the series converges to any value or even diverges; but by the commutative property of addition, terms a finite sum can be added up in any order

Comment: It just means $a+b=b+a$. This is not always the case with infinite series though, see [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, they mean the following: if $c_{ij}$ is a number for every $i = 1,\dots,m$ and $j = 1,\dots,n$, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\right) =  \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij}\right).
$$
Note that in most texts, the parentheses around the inner sum are not written explicitly (but are implied).

That these sums are equal is an "obvious" consequence of the commutativity of addition.
For instance, we can compare the two expressions in the case of $m = 2$ and $n = 3$. We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^3 c_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^2 (c_{i1} + c_{i2} + c_{i3}) = (c_{11} + c_{12} + c_{13}) + (c_{21} + c_{22} + c_{23}).
$$
On the other hand ,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{i=1}^2 c_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^3 (c_{1j} + c_{2j}) = 
(c_{11} + c_{21}) + (c_{12} + c_{22}) + (c_{13} + c_{23}).
$$
Clearly, since the same terms are being added in both sums, the two sums are equal.

---

The particular step, in detail:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^p b_{jk}c_{kl}\right) &= 
\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{k=1}^p a_{ij}b_{jk}c_{kl}\right) 
\\ &= 
\sum_{k=1}^p \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{jk}c_{kl}\right) 
= 
\sum_{k=1}^p \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{jk}\right)c_{kl}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I understood the meaning of the statement. I have now attached the proof's image as well, can you please specifically explain how it's done in the given proof as there is multiplication involved between the two summations.

Comment: @AkashSingh See my latest edit

Answer (score 1):

They probably mean that a formula such as

$$\sum_{k=k_0}^{k_1}\sum_{j=j_0(k)}^{j_1(k)} t_{jk}$$ can usually be rewritten in a form

$$\sum_{j=j_0}^{j_1}\sum_{k=k_0(j)}^{k_1(j)} t_{jk}$$ (the summation symbols have been swapped.)

The simplest case is$$\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^{n} t_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^m t_{jk}.$$

This is true because addition is commutative.